# How to get Index of Fragment in Backstack with Fragment tag name

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was able to get the fragment using the tag name as one below,

```
Fragment fragmentName = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TagName");
```

But I need to get the index of the fragment in backstack

**What I want to do**

I use the navigation with dropdown from Action Bar

So on each navigation I keep on adding the fragments without replace since I add it inside the viewpager.

So when the user selects the same page which was already added from list then i need to show that particular fragment and remove all the fragments above the current fragment.

I have the tagName of the current fragment but not the tagName of fragment above the current fragment to remove the fragments which are above the current fragment.

I tried

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack("TagName", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Above removes the fragment including the current fragment.

But I want to remove only the fragments that are above the current fragment.

Please guide me to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

To get the index of the fragment in backstack you need to use the following method :

```
private int getIndex(String tagname) {
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    for (int i = 0; i < manager.getBackStackEntryCount(); i++) {
        if (manager.getBackStackEntryAt(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(tagname)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But when you set any fragment , please insert it to backstack with tag name.

```
 fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.tabcontent, fragment, tagname);
 fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tagname);
```

I think it will work, if not please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Nitesh, but I am looking for any options without looping to the list of fragments in backstack.